# A 2TB drive won't mount (exfat), Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: mount, 22.04, hard-drive, exfat

Ubuntu  22.04.3 LTS .  The 2 terabyte USB drive is a WD "my passport ultra"
The drive icon shows up but it doesn't mount.  If I alt-click "mount"  the result is
"Error mounting device at /dev/sdb2   at /media/carl/ExIsFat  Can't read superblock on /dev/sdb2.
The Disk info tool recognizes it as exFAT ver. 1.0; there is an EFI partition 1 which is 210MB FAT(32-bit version) ; the remainder is partition 2, exFAT.

FWIW the drive mounts fine on MacOS ; it is recognized as exFat there. And other, albeit smaller, exFAT drives mount fine.

Comment: I wonder if it is something to do with 4kn versus 512e sector size, similar to what's described here [Linux (exfat-fuse) is unable to read from GPT 4TB external exFAT disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1275900/linux-exfat-fuse-is-unable-to-read-from-gpt-4tb-external-exfat-disk)

Comment: @steeldriver  sure looks like a similar problem.  Maybe someday :-) I'll reformat as exFAT under MacOS and see what happens.

Comment: Have you got gparted installed? Careful if you do, don't go formatting or deleting anything. However it would be interesting to see if it shows up in gparted and it might let you mount from there. I have found it has magic abilities sometimes...

Comment: @darth_epoxy  `gparted` sees both sdb partitions but the option to "mount" is greyed out for both of them.